# how to make the data in gridview display in arabic letters using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

When I enter the data in textbox and then click a button it should insert it in the gridview but the arabic letters shown as "??????????" like shown in the picture, I searched and found that the problem in the encoding but the problem with me is not in the web page because the web page show the arabic letters correctly , the problem in the gridview

I also try this code but its not work:

```
Response.Write("<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey You have to make sure that the content encoding for your web pages is UTF, otherwise it is not going to work. Here are few tips:

1. Make sure the datatype of your data in database table is nvarchar.
2. Make sure that the SP you are using also has nvarchar as parameter type.
3. Make request and response encoding as UTF-8. Add this in the web.config for application level encoding:

   ```
   <configuration>
    <system.web>
     <globalization
       requestEncoding="utf-8"
       responseEncoding="utf-8"/>      

    </system.web>
   ```

and add this for page level encoding:

```
<%@ Page RequestEncoding="utf-8" ResponseEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Just add this **CharSet=UTF8** to the connection string in the settings of the 
App Project.